# Scripts installed by the deb package have wrong prefix

Tags: mono, debian, packaging, deb

Building our own deb packages we've run into the issue of having to patch manually some scripts so they get the proper prefix.

In particular,

- We're building [mono](https://github.com/mono/mono)
- We're using official tarballs.
- The scripts that end up with wrong prefix are: [mcs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/scripts/mcs.in), xbuild, nunit-console4, etc

An example of a wrong script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /root/7digital-mono/mono/bin/mono \
      --debug $MONO_OPTIONS \
      /root/7digital-mono/mono/lib/mono/2.0/nunit-console.exe "$@"
```

What should be the correct end result:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono \
      --debug $MONO_OPTIONS \
      /usr/lib/mono/2.0/nunit-console.exe "$@"
```

The workaround we're using in our [build-package](https://github.com/7digital/7digital-mono/blob/master/build-package) script before calling dpkg-buildpackage:

```
sed -i s,`pwd`/mono,/usr,g $TARGET_DIR/bin/mcs
sed -i s,`pwd`/mono,/usr,g $TARGET_DIR/bin/xbuild
sed -i s,`pwd`/mono,/usr,g $TARGET_DIR/bin/nunit-console
sed -i s,`pwd`/mono,/usr,g $TARGET_DIR/bin/nunit-console2
sed -i s,`pwd`/mono,/usr,g $TARGET_DIR/bin/nunit-console4
```

Now, what is the CORRECT way to fix this? Full debian package creation scripts [here](https://github.com/7digital/7digital-mono/).

Disclaimer: I know there are preview packages of Mono 3 [here](https://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/)! But those don't work for Squeeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the proper way is to *not* call `./configure --prefix=$TARGET_DIR`

this tells all the binaries/scripts/... that the installated files will end up in `${TARGET_DIR}`, whereas they really should endup in `/usr`.

you can use the `DESTDIR` variable (as in `make install DESTDIR=${TARGET_DIR}`) to change (prefix) the installation target at install time (files will end-up in `${TARGET_DIR}/${prefix}` but will only have `${prefix}` "built-in")

Comment: mmm, when I do that, it fails, I'll grab the error ASAP and let you know

Comment: what are you doing, and how does it fail?

Comment: test -z "/usr/share/libgc-mono" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/share/libgc-mono"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/libgc-mono': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-dist_pkgdataDATA] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lockerteam/7digital-mono/mono-3.0.3/libgc/doc'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lockerteam/7digital-mono/mono-3.0.3/libgc/doc'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lockerteam/7digital-mono/mono-3.0.3/libgc'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: so this means it's trying to install in /usr in the machine that builds the deb, why?

Comment: mmm, one sec, I think the problem is in my script, maybe I should be using DESTDIR="$TARGET_DIR" instead of DESTDIR=$(TARGET_DIR) ? testing....

Comment: it turns out it doesn't really work, I'm getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187344/dpkg-buildpackage-uc-us-b-fails-with-dpkg-shlibdeps-error-couldnt-find-li the reason I may not have noticed before is that I could have the previous package installed, and that made the new deb package generation work; but in a vanilla debian squeeze with no mono, it fails