# dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b fails with "dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libmono-2.0.so.1 needed by ...monodis."

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

Trying to build simple .deb packages with [this script](https://github.com/7digital/7digital-mono/blob/master/build-package) is failing with this:

```
   dh_installexamples
   dh_installman
   dh_installcatalogs
   dh_installcron
   dh_installdebconf
   dh_installemacsen
   dh_installifupdown
   dh_installinfo
   dh_pysupport
   dh_installinit
   dh_installmenu
   dh_installmime
   dh_installmodules
   dh_installlogcheck
   dh_installlogrotate
   dh_installpam
   dh_installppp
   dh_installudev
   dh_installwm
   dh_installxfonts
   dh_bugfiles
   dh_lintian
   dh_gconf
   dh_icons
   dh_perl
   # Skipping dh_usrlocal - empty override
   dh_link
   dh_compress
   dh_fixperms
   dh_strip
   dh_makeshlibs
   dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libmono-2.0.so.1 needed by debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/monodis (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '').
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/7digital-mono.substvars debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/mono debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/mprof-report debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/mono-sgen debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/pedump debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/monograph debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/monodis debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mcs.exe.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libMonoSupportW.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libikvm-native.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmono-2.0.so.1.0.0 debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so.0.0.0 debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-cov.so.0.0.0 debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so.0.0.0 debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.0.0.0 debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so.0.0.0 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 9
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: btw, why don't you let dpkg-buildpackage run configure for you?

Comment: `dh` should automatically take care of this; if your sources (including `configure` script) are not in the root, you might have to specify them with `--sourcedirectory` flag; check `man dh`

Comment: wait a sec, if I don't call configure I cannot call make either, are you saying that dpkg-buildpackage would do that for me as well?

Comment: yes, dpkg-configure automates the **entire** build-process

Comment: i think the problems you are facing are mainly due to the fact, that you try to create a debian-package for various versions of upstream with a single toolchain; you probably should *not* do that...the entire packging process in debian is optimized to track specific versions of upstream, and eventually introduce sub-versions (for debian related fixes); checkout [GitPackagingWorkflow](http://wiki.debian.org/GitPackagingWorkflow)

Comment: ok, but if I just call dpkg-configure, how can I tell it the folder in which it should run the build process?

Comment: use the "--sourcedirectory" flag for dh in your `debian/rules`

Answer (score 3):

it means that the binary found (during the build-process) as `debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/bin/monodis` (and which will likely end up as `/usr/bin/monodis`) is linking against `libmono-2.0.so.1` but this file cannot be found.

i suspect that the .so-file is part of your package as well (though you haven't given any clue about this), so it's not yet installed on the target system.

what i find most strange is the double occurence of `usr` in your path, which might well indicate where the problem lies: dpkg-shlibdeps (by means of the linker) probably looks for the .so-file in the standard paths (e.g. `usr/lib`) *and* in the package paths (e.g. `debian/7digital-mono/usr/lib`), but it will not look into `debian/7digital-mono/usr/usr/lib`

Comment: Yes, the .so file should be compiled by the package I'm building. I have the impression that all this is caused by a mono regression in the build: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10874

Answer (score 1):

Change `"debian/rules"` file accordingly to indicate the right path to `LD_LIBRARY`

Search for `"dh binary-arch"` in rules file and replace with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/lib/i386-linux-gnu dh binary-arch
```

OR

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/path-1-to-shared-library:/path-2-to-shared-library dh binary-arch
```

OR

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/path-to-shared-library dh binary-arch
```